# How to redirect command output to a build-in command in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

for example:

I want cd to another directory, the directory is the ourtput of "where xxx"

so, I type:

where xxx | cd

but this doesn't work, the cd is a build in command of cmd.exe

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but it should work: `for /f %d in ('where xxx') do cd %d` - See `for /?` for details.  For example, you'll need to use two `%` if you're using this in batch files, and the single quotes are important.

Comment: @Marged - That link does show how to get the output of a command into a variable, but as the first answer explains, you cannot do it with a pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

go2.bat

```
@echo off

cd %~dp$PATH:1
```

And using it:

```
go2 somefile.txt
```